# Проблема с пониманием утилиты chpst из runit

Tags: администрирование, linux

Пытаюсь запустить node.js как демон при помощи runit, вот скрипт run с лимитом в 250 мб памяти:

```
#!/bin/shcd /home/artemexec 2>&1exec chpst -u artem -m 262144000 node test.js >> production.log 2>&1
```

Так работает, утилита top пишет что node весит 9 мб, а если укажу 50 мб лимита то запуска не происходит выводится timeout: down: artem: 1s, normally up, want up

Не понимаю в чем подвох, ведь node весит в памяти всего 9 мб, а при лимите в 50 мб не запускается.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не знаю, что это)

Может это поможет разобраться: [использование runit вместо Init и вывод логов в файл](http://kuroikaze85.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/runit-nodejs/).

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего, во время инициализации требуется больше памяти, чем после окончания этого процесса.